# Ionic 3 - setup global variables from server side data on first app load

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm working on ionic 3 application which requires to load app settings from server before it navigates to the firstPage(Tab1). Basically, i need to load settings while showing the splash screen to the user.

After getting the settings I need to assign to a global variable/object, so that I can use it in the application without reloading the settings in each and every tab change.

*Note: If the user kills the app and re-launch, I want to load the settings again before going to the FirstPage(Tab1).*

Which is the best place and the event to handle this operation? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All this is a theoretical example so you will have to create your own code*

> You can use **APP_INITIALIZER** from Angular core
>   [Example](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/performing-action-before-app-start/75592/6)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";
import { GlobalProvider} from "../providers/global/global";

export function init_app(global: GlobalProvider){
    // Init required providers before load the app
    // NOTE: this factory needs to return a function (that then returns a promise)
    return () => global.load()  // + any other providers...
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    GlobalProvider,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init_app,
      deps: [GlobalProvider],
      multi: true
    },
    ....
  ]
})
```

---

> Create a provider: **ionic g provider global** 
>   [Example](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-on-any-files-in-ionic/103294/5)

### Declare your variables in a new Provider

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    /*
      Generated class for the GlobalProvider provider.
    */
    @Injectable()
    export class GlobalProvider {

      public myGlobalVar: string;

      public async load() { ... }

    }
```

### Use this in other .ts files like below

```
import { GlobalProvider } from "../../providers/global/global";

constructor( public global: GlobalProvider) { }
```

### Use in template file like below

```
<ion-content>
  <h1>{{ global.myGlobalVar }} </h1>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Excellent. Working as expected. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in app.component.ts, may be in initialize() function, called in a constructor. The function may be like:

```ts
protected initializeApp() {   
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //Your code
     });
}
```